# How can I clean an area rug without a vacuum cleaner?

Tags: cleaning, substitute-tool, carpet

I have a 5' × 7' area rug with a fairly long nap and no vacuum cleaner. I try to keep it fairly clean, but when walking over it, the dirt is fairly noticeable that sticks to my bare feet. It's winter, so I can't take it out and beat it, what are some good alternatives?

Comment: There really isn't a good way to clean the rug without a vacuum cleaner short of taking it outside and shaking it off, and then beating it with a broom. Try to find a day that isn't too cold and dress appropriately. Doing this indoors will just kick all the dust into the air and settle on everything. It may also trigger allergies.

Answer (score 2):

Turn the rug upside down. Roll the rug up, and while rolling, knock the dirt off with a broom, a hand, or whatever works. This should leave all the dirt on the floor to be swept up. Making a large roll will provide a good-sized vertical face for the dirt to fall from.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an old cloth lint remover like this

[image: old style cloth lint remover]

or even something made of rubber with grooves such as this pet grooming tool 
[image: zoomgroom]
, you can just rub and these will lift tons of stuff out of the rug that you didn't even know were there. I've used both of these on carpets in my stairs.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Like a [Sticky Buddy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jlSF0dtDRD8)?

Comment: lol... not sure if you wanted to use that video... it's the dubbed version... Anyways, that might work to get surface dirt off, but it will not dig.

Answer (score 1):

I use 2 inch wide clear tape. also try slipping nylon stocking or pantyhose over your broom and sweep the carpet. It's not perfect but I am tired of the vacuum cleaners that don't really work better either.  Since the days of the cylinder electrolux, I have not found a vac that really works